# How to repeat an IF statement

Tags: programming, c++

My LCD info is called from an IF statement but since it's clock and temperature info i don't want to just show the information but update the information constantly in real time.
i don't want to use (while) loop or any other "code-blocking".

Here's the whole code:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <DS3231.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>


#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2
int Heater= 3;
int Switch1= 4;

Time t;
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);
DS3231  rtc(SDA, SCL);
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

// Push button

boolean oldSwitchState = LOW;
boolean newSwitchState = LOW;
boolean lcdScroll = LOW;
boolean lcdBacklight = LOW;
boolean lcdWelcome = LOW;

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long BacklightTime = 10000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(Heater, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Switch1, INPUT);
  lcd.begin();
  rtc.begin();
}
void loop() {
  float testTemp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  t = rtc.getTime();
  if(lcdWelcome == LOW){
      lcd.setCursor(0,0);
      lcd.print("Welcome, Admin!");
      lcd.setCursor(0,1);
      lcd.print("press Start");
  }

  // LCD
  newSwitchState = digitalRead(Switch1);
    if (millis() - previousMillis >= BacklightTime) {
      lcd.noBacklight();
      lcdBacklight = LOW;
    }
    else if ( lcdBacklight == LOW ){
      lcd.backlight();
      lcdBacklight = HIGH;
    }
    if ( newSwitchState != oldSwitchState ) {
       if ( newSwitchState == HIGH ){
       previousMillis = millis();
       lcdWelcome = HIGH;
       lcd.clear();
      if ( lcdScroll == LOW ){
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print(testTemp);
        lcd.print("   ");
        lcd.print(rtc.getTimeStr());
        lcdScroll = HIGH;
      }
      else{
        lcd.setCursor(0,0);
        lcd.print(rtc.getDOWStr());
        lcd.print("   ");
        lcd.print(rtc.getDateStr());
        lcdScroll = LOW;
      }
       }
       oldSwitchState = newSwitchState;
    }
}
```

How can i update the functions inside the `if(lcdScroll == LOW){}` and `else{}` statements constantly to show on display?

Comment: please use `true` and `false` as boolean values

Comment: @Juraj thanks but does it make any difference?

Comment: I'm not clear on what your problem is - I don't see any blocking code here - you test the clock and the switches and either act on them or don't, which is appropriate. Also, what do you mean by "How to repeat an IF statement"?

Comment: Also, do not compare values with true, false, 1, 0, or HIGH or LOW, just write if (variable), by default all nonzero values will result in executing the if statement.

Comment: well your void loop() is already a while loop.....What is it that you are wanting to repeat that is not already happening?

Comment: @JRobert the problem is code inside `if (lcdScroll == LOW){}` only runs once but if i want to have the time to update in real time, time functions have to be in a loop not only run once.

Comment: Well, it runs once per `loop()`. If the rest of the code is implemented properly, `loop()` will be fast and you have everything you want. I don't see any blocking code like `delays()`, etc. So what was the problem again?

Comment: Maybe it is happening so fast OP can not see the scrolling - giving the **appearance** that it is only running once.???? What happens if you put some serial.println's in your code? Does the if statement get executed more than once then when you press "the button"???

Comment: @SimSon if we add a `Serial.prinln("test");` to `if (lcdScroll == LOW){}` statement you'll see that when push button pressed the code inside that statement only runs once. i think what i need is a "state machine" to get this to work...

Comment: Ah, now I got it, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you suggested in your comment, you can implement a state machine, but the simplest would probably be setting a flag `bool a_flag` in this `if(lcdScroll==LOW)` clause and checking `if(a_flag)` in the highest scope of the `loop()` section. This is where you `print("test");`.

In respect to your code this will look like:

```
bool a_flag=false;
void loop() {
  // some irrelevant stuff
  if ( newSwitchState != oldSwitchState) {
    // some stuff
    if ( lcdScroll == LOW ){
      // stuff you would handle here
      a_flag=true;
    }
    else {
      // stuff you would handle here
      a_flag=false;
    }
  }
  if (a_flag) Serial.println("lcdScroll is LOW");
  else Serial.println("lcdScroll is HIGH");
}
```

Beside this general solution you could simply do the following in your specific case:

```
loop(){

  // your actual code

  if (lcdScroll) Serial.println("lcdScroll is LOW");
  else Serial.println("lcdScroll is HIGH");
}
```

Comment: i'm very new to this can you please implant that in the code so i can get the whole idea?

Comment: @newbie You need to clear this flag somewhere and I'm not sure where (probably in the corresponding `else{}`). I'll add an implementation of this soon...

Comment: See my example implementation. This will **continuously** print the corresponding message. Note also that the backlight will behave erronuously when millis runs over!

Comment: i asked this question both in reddit and arduino forum and they didn't/couldn't give me an answer. you sir are a legend. thank you and god bless you.